# Given $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{g(\alpha)}$, find the minimal polynomial $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{1/g(\alpha)}$, where $\alpha$ is the root of the polynomial $p(X)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, minimal-polynomials

Suppose that $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ is the root of a polynomial $p(X)$.
Let $g(X)$ be a polynomial such that $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{g(\alpha)}$ is the minimal polynomial of $g(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Is there a general way for finding the minimal polynomial $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{1/g(\alpha)}$ of $\frac{1}{g(\alpha)} \in \mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

In particular, I have $\alpha$ to be the root of $p(X) = X^3 - X - 1$.
Furthermore, let $g(X) = X^2 + 1$, than $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\alpha^2 + 1} = X^3 - 5X^2 + 8X - 5$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2223606/714378).
I would like to find the minimal polynomial of $1/(\alpha^2+1)$. Is there a general/clever way to encounter this problem without a lot of calculation?

Comment: $x^{n}f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{g(\alpha)}(1/x)$, for $n=\deg(f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{g(\alpha)})$.

Comment: Yes, that is trivial, thanks :)

Comment: Exponents to polynomials actually mean something (at least for some values of the exponent), please don't abuse the superscript position for stuffing arguments of the notation.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen could you please elaborate on that? The $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{g(\alpha)}$ is just notation right?

Comment: It is just a very bad notation. The sentence that introduces it does not help either, as (a) it does not say it is introducing a notation, and (b) it says "such that" but is is not at all giving a condition that the polynomial $g$ needs to satisfy.